# Drop Dox to Index Match Match Loop _ Excel

Tags: excel, vba, portfolio

**The Objective:** I am making a Portfolio Tracker.

I created a Drop Dox Menu and and an Index Match Match to pull from a portfolio. The Drop Down selects the stock and then the index match match selects the stock with the relevant column keys.

`INDEX('Data Dump'!$B$2:$S1002,MATCH('Landing Page'!$F$6,'Data Dump'!$T$2:$T1002,0),MATCH(B$8,'Data Dump'!$B$1:$T$1,0))`.

F6 is based on the Drop Down Value, so ideally will shift dynamically.
[this is an image of the dashboard: INTC is F6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHusA.png)

**The Issue:** based on current criteria, the worksheet can only complete one row and when pulled down repeats the same value.

I've been trying to find a formula or code that will:

1. Pull the list when a new stock is selected
2. Loop till all unique values of the rows are found based on the second match

Is this possible? Or should I break my worksheet into more pieces.

Comment: Your formula references are absolute (indicated by the `$`), so they will not adjust on dragging/filling.  Try `F6` instead of `$F$6`

Comment: Tim thanks! The problem I want to keep that as F6 indicates where I select the drop down. So for example, I want to only select holders of Intel so I select INTC in F6 and it populates the rest of the sheet

Comment: MATCH only returns a single value - you will need some type of array formula-based approach if you want to populate multiple rows   Eg: https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-multiple-matches-into-separate-rows

Comment: Ok.  Yeah going to have to reconfigure the sheet. I can't array a thousand IDs, but thanks for helping